# .ts file isn't treated as TypeScript module

Tags: typescript, systemjs

[Here is SystemJS + TypeScript plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/uLJzcKK05wDdUKXtKMuq?p=preview), created from [official Angular plunk template](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5).

It throws

> (SystemJS) SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration
>
> at eval ()
>
> ...

error and obviously evaluates .ts file as ordinary JavaScript when the file doesn't contain `import` or `export` statements:

*main.ts*

```
const foo: boolean = 'foo';

console.log(foo);
```

*config.js*

```
System.config({
  //use typescript for compilation
  transpiler: 'typescript',
  //typescript compiler options
  typescriptOptions: {
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true
  },
  paths: {
    'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
  },
  //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  map: {

    'app': './src',
    ...
  },
  //packages defines our app package
  packages: {
    app: {
      main: './main.ts',
      defaultExtension: 'ts'
    },
    ...
  }
});
```

*index.html*

```
...
<script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.31/dist/system.js"></script>
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script>
System.import('app')
  .catch(console.error.bind(console));
</script>
...
```

But [the same plunk is fine](https://plnkr.co/edit/jV66uvzbfCLbPYW3dcUU?p=preview) when the file has signs of ES6 module:

*main.ts*

```
const foo: boolean = 'foo';

console.log(foo);

export default null;
```

Obviously, if a file has .ts extension, I would prefer to evaluate it as TypeScript, whether it imports something or not.

Why does this happen in this setup? How can this be fixed?

Comment: You should be using `plugin-typescript`. `systemjs` does not come with transpiler so just `transpiler: 'typescript'` does not work

Comment: I don't think it's true. TS works if there is `export` statement. This is what the question says. Otherwise `const foo: boolean = 'foo'` would throw a syntax error, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SystemJS will probably work as follows:**

```
> System.import('app')
  - where is 'app'?
> map: { 'app': './src', ...
  - Okay, 'app' is './src'
  - './src' ??
> packages: { app: { main: './main.ts',
  - Aha, './src/main.ts'
> ./src/main.ts
  - Which format??
  - 'system' ? -> No
  - 'esm' ? -> No (if YES, use transpiler: 'typescript')
  - 'amd' ? -> No
  - 'cjs' ? -> No
  - 'global' ? -> Yes -> No transpiler needed.
> evaluate ./src/main.ts
  - What is ':string' in JavaScript?
  - Exception!!!
```

[Module format detection](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md#module-format-detection)

> When the module format is not set, automatic regular-expression-based
>   detection is used. This module format detection is never completely
>   accurate, but caters well for the majority use cases.

If auto-detection fails, you must specify it manually.

**Method 1: Add hints to source**

ex1: add `export` (from question)

```
const foo: boolean = 'foo';
console.log(foo);
export default null;
```

ex2: add `export`

```
export const foo: boolean = 'foo';
console.log(foo);
```

**Method 2: Add `format` configuration**

ex1: packages / path / meta / pattern(./main.ts or ./*.ts) / `format`

```
packages: {
    app: {
      main: './main.ts',
      defaultExtension: 'ts',
      meta: {
       './main.ts': {
           format: 'esm'
        }
      } 
    }
```

ex2: packages / path / `format`

```
packages: {
    app: {
      main: './main.ts',
      defaultExtension: 'ts',
      format: 'esm'
    }
}
```

ex3: meta / pattern (need app/ prefix) / `format` (outside packages)

```
meta: {
    'app/main.ts': {
        format: 'esm'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:** This comes from just a little debugging, I'm not actually experienced in the subject so any corrections to my understanding are welcome.

SystemJS will only perform transpilation if the module format is determined properly. If the module format is not informed, it uses a fast heuristic to try and determine it (basically, a regular expression over the source).
This heuristic works when you have the *import* statement and fails when you don't.
The actual fix for your set up is to add the module format explicitly to the package like so:

```
app: {
  main: './main.ts',
  defaultExtension: 'ts',
  format:'esm' // << Module format.
},
```

Comment: Thanks, the question doesn't contain full explanation but hits the bull's eye any way.